# How to create a better table suitable for publication in R

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, knitr

I have a table summarising the total number of people who responded yes (1), no (0) (or missing values) to a list of food types consumed in the past 24 hours.

data example:

```
df <- structure (list(
  subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-1945"), 
  grain_12m = c("1","1","1","0","0",""),
  cer_12m = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", ""), 
  egg_12m = c("0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0"),
  poultry_12m = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
  meat_12m = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1"), 
  form_milk_12m = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "", ""), 
  oilfat_12m = c("0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"),
  junk_12m = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Code:

```
nutrients_summary <- df %>% data.frame() %>% 
  select(subject_id, grain_12m:junk_12m) |>
  pivot_longer(-subject_id, names_to = "Nutrients") |>
  group_by(Nutrients) |>
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    Yes = sum(value %in% 1),
    No = sum(value %in% 0), 
    "NA" = sum(is.na(value))
  ) |>
  mutate(across(c(No, Yes, `NA`), ~ paste0(.x, " (", round(100 * .x / n), ")"))) |>
  rename_with(~ paste0(.x, " (%)"), c(No, Yes, `NA`)) |>
  select(-n) %>%
  arrange(desc('Yes')) %>%
  print(n = Inf)
```

Table with the df above

[image]

Table from the Rmarkdown (Ignore the different numbers and variables)
[image]

Now, I have a few questions:

1. I want to arrange the tables by column "Yes", but the current code with  `arrange` function is not working. How do I fix this?
2. How to I ensure the rowwise percentage totals are correct?
3. The table itself doesn't look neat. How can I polish it to look like a table suitable for publishing?
4. General rmarkdown (PDF output) question - how do I remove the ## at the start of each line

Comment: Adding [gtsummary](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/) here.

Comment: Needs more focus

This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Answer (score 1):

As Thandi mentioned in the comment, there are different packages to create table.
One function that might be particularly helpful for you is TOne() in the DescTools package.

```
df_nutr <- df |>
  select(subject_id, grain_12m:junk_12m) |>
  pivot_longer(-subject_id, names_to = "Nutrients")


library(DescTools)

TOne(df_nutr$Nutrients, grp = df_nutr$value)
```

There are many settings to adjust the table and with the function ToWrd() from the same package an easy way to export the table to MS-Word.

```
wrd <- GetNewWrd()
ToWrd(
  TOne(df_nutr$Nutrients, grp = df_nutr$value),
)
```